# The action "Run AppleScript" was not loaded because it has an invalid signature

Tags: applescript, automator

I was setting up some keyboard actions by using Automator.
First I used "Watch Me Do" to record but it couldn't work with Chrome so after recording with WMD I dragged it out of the box to create an AppleScript for those actions.
I assigned keyboard shortcuts and all works well.
Then I didn't know how to export/import these actions to another MAC so I tried copying the Run AppleScript.action file to the Automator Library.
It prompted me to "Install" and I clicked Install.
Now it brings the message: "The action "Run AppleScript" was not loaded because it has an invalid signature" and I can't use AppleScript at all now.
I tried dragging from WMD like before or "Run AppleScript" from the Automator menu but still the same message.
Please help! Thanks in advance. Here's the error
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u38sT.png)

Comment: You don’t copy the action, you copy the script, which is what the action uses.  What OS are you running?

Comment: yeah. I thought they would store the script in the action file as a database :( now I'm just trying to get AppleScript to run at all. I'm running on Big Sur

Comment: In Big Sur the system is write-only, so you don’t have permission to overwrite the original system action.  Look in your user’s **~/Library/Automator** folder and just delete any `Run AppleScript` action that was copied there.

Comment: I thought about that but it would not let me delete any files in that folder :(

Comment: You can't delete files in your own user folder?

Comment: nope, tried it and it wouldn't let me :(

Comment: @red_menace, at least on my Catalina Automator actions are located in the **/Library/Automator/** folder. That is, on the **system domain**. All actions owner is **system**, but **admin** has read/write permissions on them. And can delete them providing the admin password.